# Wrap an X amount of taxonomy posts in a separate Row in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I am trying to create a slider with taxonomy post categories and its Posts so the structure will look like this

```
Row 1
    First Category Title
      First category Post Title Goes Here
    Second Category Title
      Second category Post Title Goes Here
Row 2
    Third Category Title
      Third category Post Title Goes Here
    Fourth Category Title
      Fourth category Post Title Goes Here
```

So what i tried currently for getting the taxonomy category and its posts is teh below snippet

```
<div class="clientsListRow">
                    <?php 
                        $post_type = 'clients';
                        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies(array( 'post_type' => $post_type));
                        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) :
                            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
                            foreach($terms as $term) : ?>
                              <ul><li><a><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
                                <?php
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                                        )
                                    )
                                );
                                $posts = new WP_Query($args);
                                if($posts->have_posts()): ?>
                                <ul>
                                <?php  while($posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                                    <li><a><?php  echo get_the_title(); ?></a></li>
                                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                                </ul></li></ul>
                            <?php endforeach;
                        endforeach; 
                    ?>
                </div>
```

But could not manage to create the separating part with a div so i wrap every row with X amount of uls in a div.

ANy ideas how i achieve this?

Comment: Generally speaking you need to replace your foreach loops with incrementing loops. So instead of `foreach` you will have `for($i=0; $i<count($terms); $i++)` etc. If you can add your exact desired HTML output I think I can help you achieve it. I assume each row needs an outer `<div class="row">` then within the row I am asking what structure you need - should category titles be `<h2>`s and post titles be wrapped inside `<div>`s?

Comment: The general output is to have 6 categories in each row with their subcategories. I have categories in ul li so <div class="row1"><ul><li><a></a><ul>with its subcats</ul></li></ul></div>. I also need to separate each 3 categories inside that one row. Thank you for the help @WebElaine

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close. The key is to use iterating loops and check which iteration you're on to determine whether or not to output a new `<div class="row">`, open or close a `<ul>`, etc.

Note that one you are in a loop, you can just use `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` because the query already grabbed them, no need to `echo get_the_title()` etc.

```
<div class="clientsListRow"><?php 
    $post_type = 'clients';
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies(array('post_type' => $post_type));
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) :
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        for($t=1; $t<=count($terms); $t++) {
            // if "t" is 1 or a multiple of 7, start a new row
            if($t == 1 || $t%7 == 0) { ?><div class="row"><?php }
                // if "t" is 1 or a multiple of 4, start a new list
                if($t == 1 || $t%4 == 0) { ?><ul><?php } ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $term->slug,
                            )
                        )
                    );
                    $posts = new WP_Query($args);
                    if($posts->have_posts()) : ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php while($posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php // if "t" is a multiple of 3, or the very last item, close the list
            if($t%3 == 0 || $t == count($terms)) { ?></ul><?php
            // if "t" is a multiple of 6, or the very last item, close the row
            if($t%6 == 0 || $t == count($terms)) { ?></div><!-- end row --><?php
        }
    endforeach; ?>
</div>
```